# ruby on rails devise edit not working when i use modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, modal-dialog, edit

I am using devise gem and Semantic UI modal.

I do sign-in and sign-up in homepage.html.erb.

I changed

```
devise/session/new.html.erb to devise/sesseion/_new.html.erb
```

so i can use `<%= render devise/session/new %>`

Sign-up and sign-in are working well when I use modal but edit is not working when using modal.

What is the problem in my code?

**homepage.html.erb**

```
<div class="ui longer modal">
  <div>
    <%= render "devise/registrations/edit" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**devise/registrations/_edit.html.erb**

```
<%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:remote => true, :class => 'ui form'}) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>


 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tel %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :tel, autofocus: true, placeholder: current_user.tel, autocomplete: "tel" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :nickname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :nickname, autofocus: true, placeholder: current_user.nickname, autocomplete: "nickname" %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :profile_img %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :profile_img, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "profile_img" %>
  </div>


  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <br />
      <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "edit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= button_to "membership withdrawal", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %>
```

**route.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "users/passwords", :confirmations => "users/confirmations", registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions'}

    devise_scope :user do 
      get   'registrations' => 'devise/registrations#create'

      get   'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit'

      delete 'users/sign_out' => 'devise/sesssions#destroy'
    end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
     additional_params = [:name, :tel, :nickname, :profile_img]
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: additional_params)

      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:tel, :nickname, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) 
  end
```

**Routes**

```
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action

new_user_session_path   GET /users/sign_in(.:format)    users/sessions#new
user_session_path   POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    users/sessions#create
destroy_user_session_path   GET /users/sign_out(.:format)   users/sessions#destroy
user_password_path  POST    /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#create
new_user_password_path  GET /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password_path GET /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
PATCH   /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
PUT /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration_path   GET /users/cancel(.:format) users/registrations#cancel
user_registration_path  POST    /users(.:format)    users/registrations#create
new_user_registration_path  GET /users/sign_up(.:format)    users/registrations#new
edit_user_registration_path GET /users/edit(.:format)   users/registrations#edit
PATCH   /users(.:format)    users/registrations#update
PUT /users(.:format)    users/registrations#update
DELETE  /users(.:format)    users/registrations#destroy
registrations_path  GET /registrations(.:format)    devise/registrations#create
GET /users/edit/:id(.:format)   devise/registrations#edit
users_path  PATCH   /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
PUT /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#update
DELETE  /users(.:format)    users/registrations#destroy
users_sign_out_path DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sesssions#destroy
root_path   GET /   fjob#homepage
fjob_homepage_path  GET /fjob/homepage(.:format)    fjob#homepage
fjob_create_path    GET /fjob/create(.:format)  fjob#create
review_create_review_path   GET /review/create_review(.:format) review#create_review
users_sign_up_path  GET /users/sign_up(.:format)    users#sign_up
fjob_default_fjob_path  GET /fjob/default_fjob(.:format)    fjob#default_fjob
GET /users/sign_out(.:format)   users#sign_out
users_edit_path GET /users/edit(.:format)   users#edit
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def resource_class
    User
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

end
```

Logs

```
started POST "/users" for 222.98.34.68 at 2018-08-23 08:19:01 +0000
Cannot render console from 222.98.34.68! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"tel"=>"123456", "nickname"=>"123123", "profile_img"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"회원 정보 수정"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
Redirected to https://find-kim-esdx245.c9users.io/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/" for 222.98.34.68 at 2018-08-23 08:19:01 +0000
Cannot render console from 222.98.34.68! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by FjobController#homepage as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Fjob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "fjobs".* FROM "fjobs" WHERE "fjobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Rendered devise/sessions/_new.html.erb (4.9ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/_new.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/_edit.html.erb (7.2ms)
  Fjob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "fjobs".* FROM "fjobs"
  Fjob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "fjobs".* FROM "fjobs" WHERE "fjobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Review Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "fjobs".* FROM "fjobs" WHERE "fjobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Review Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Fjob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "fjobs".* FROM "fjobs" WHERE "fjobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Review Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered fjob/homepage.erb within layouts/application (25.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 26.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: yes! i can't see any errors!  In the _edit.html.erb, click the submit but not change nickname, tel and password.

Comment: When you click the `edit` button/icon, can you paste the trace logs here ?

Comment: sorry. i'm immature. how can i find the trace logs?

Comment: What I meant is, after you perform any action such as a button click, the request goes to a controller and so on and so forth. You can see that request in the console(terminal), where you're running rails server. That's the log. So, click the `edit` button and share the logs you see.

Comment: When you go to the edit form, is it prefilled with the current_user's data or blank?

Comment: it is prefilled with current_user's data

Comment: Please add the logs as @KedarnagMukanahallipatna suggested.

Comment: @Kedarnag Mukanahallipatna. logs are so long. so i paste logs above the body

Comment: @한철민 Go ahead paste the logs, if that is not what we're looking for, we'll ask you to change it. Just edit the OP with the logs.